# iOS: Is it in any way possible to keep the device id after uninstalling app?

Tags: ios, deviceid

So until now I know that I can get the device id of apple device using the `identifierForVendor`. But reading through many answers I found out that this id is not unique because it will change after user uninstall and reinstall the app. I am an android developer and this doesn't happen in android (the device id in android is independent of uninstalling and reinstalling the app). I need your help to understand how to do the same in ios.

I want to keep the device id even after uninstalling the app.

Comment: You can put your own uuid in the keychain. This will remain until the device is erased.

Comment: @Paulw11 what do you mean by the device is erased? Something like factory reset in android?

Comment: Yes, if the user selects "erase all data" then the keychain is erased and it is essentially a new device.

Comment: @Paulw11 you mean the "erase iphone" button? right?

Comment: It is actually "Erase all content and settings"

Comment: @Paulw11 yes you are right but after that comes the button "erase iphone" it has red color.

Comment: @Paulw11 this also means that keychain persists even after a user delete the data of a single app from the settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183181/discussion-between-paulw11-and-data).